# How to Decode map golang

Tags: go

I run my code and I get map like that:
`map[from:0 key:<nil> price:Desc title:stack]`
I want to get value `from`,`price`,`title`

please help me

Comment: Please expand on your problem.  What have you tried?  What errors are you getting?  Include the portion of the code that you're working with

Comment: I learn jwt in golang, ex: I want to get `title` so when I run code I get `stack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your map constructed, you can access a value of the map by providing the key.  The syntax is:

```
value := myMap[myKey]
```

The key's type can be any type that can be evaluated by a comparison operator ( `>=`, `==`, `<=`, etc...).  For your example it looks like you are using strings for keys.

Here's an example:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{
    "from": 0,
    "key": nil,
    "price": "Desc",
    "title": "task",
}

// Get the value of price
price := m["price"]
fmt.Println(price)

// Get the title
title := m["title"]
fmt.Println(title)

// Loop through all of the map's key-value pairs
for key, value := range m {
    fmt.Println(key, ":", value)
}
```

[Example in Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/8a4u9AS2pq)